# Parse JSON string by escaping characters

Tags: java, json, string, string-parsing

I am receiving the below string from DB.

```
{
    "MyDetails": {
        "Type1": "A",
        "Type2": "B",
        "Type3": "C",
        "Type4": "D",
        "Type5": "E",
        "Type6": "F",
        "Date1": "2000-02-11"
    }
}
```

I have created the syntax to parse JSON string but the above format is giving me an error String with which am not able to construct a String.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{MYDETAILS:{TYPE: A,CLASS: B}}");
System.out.println(obj);
JSONObject array = obj.getJSONObject("MYDETAILS");
System.out.println(array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  System.out.println(array.getString("CLASS"));
}
```

How do i convert the string from DB into a valid string in Java?

I guess that should give me the answer .

The problem is with the string data received from DB and am not able to convert into a String.

How to remove the quotes dynamically so that i can form a valid string?

Comment: What do you receive? The JSON or `{MYDETAILS:{TYPE: A,CLASS: B}}`?

Comment: I am unable to parse this {
    "MyDetails": {
        "Type1": "A",
        "Type2": "B",
        "Type3": "C",
        "Type4": "D",
        "Type5": "E",
        "Type6": "F",
        "Date1": "2000-02-11"
    }
}

Comment: Because of the number of double quotes present am not able to get it as a String in java.

Comment: If you want to use a literal string for a test case you must "escape" all the internal quotes: `new JSONObject("{ \"MyDetails\": { \"Type1\": \"A\", \"Type2\": \"B\", ... } }")`

Answer (score 2):

To parse this JSON

```
{
    "MyDetails": {
        "Type1": "A",
        "Type2": "B",
        "Type3": "C",
        "Type4": "D",
        "Type5": "E",
        "Type6": "F",
        "Date1": "2000-02-11"
    }
}
```

you would use something like this:

```
JSONObject root = ...;
JSONObject details = (JSONObject) root.get("MyDetails");
String type1 = (String) details.get("Type1");
String type2 = (String) details.get("Type2");
// and so on
```

Comment: Hi Lutz

Am having trouble passing the response as an argument in java

Comment: {"GVTIDDTL":{"GVTID_TY_CD":"NIC","OTH_GOVT_ID_TY_TX":"NATIONAL IDENTIFICATION CARD","GVTID":"ID","GVT_ISS_ST_CD":"NY","GVT_ISS_CNTRY_CD":"840","GVTID_ISS_DT":"2010-02-01","GVTID_XPRN_DT":"2019-02-11"}}

Comment: There is some strange whitespace in `GVTID_ISS_DT":‌​"2010-02-01` in you last comment which breaks even http://jsonlint.com/ Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are confused about JSON encoding, this string you have is a single instance of the MyDetails object and you could parse it like this:

```
JSONObject ob = obj.getJSONObject("MYDETAILS");
System.out.println(ob.getString("CLASS"));
```

If it were true that MyDetails is in fact an array then the JSON would instead use square brackets like this:

```
{"MyDetails": [
      {  "CLASS": "A" },
      {  "CLASS": "B"},      
    ]}
```

In which case your code would be:

```
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("MYDETAILS");
System.out.println(array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
  System.out.println(array.get(i).getString("CLASS"));
}
```

Hope you can see the difference now.

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{MYDETAILS:{TYPE: A,CLASS: B}}");
is working fine.It is the way i tried out. but the real response is JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{"GVTIDDTL":{"GVTID_TY_CD":"NIC","OTH_GOVT_ID_TY_TX":"NATIONAL IDENTIFICATION CARD","GVTID":"ID","GVT_ISS_ST_CD":"NY","GVT_ISS_CNTRY_CD":"840","GVTID_ISS_DT":"2010-02-01","GVTID_XPRN_DT":"2019-02-11"}}");

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{"GVTIDDTL":{"GVTID_TY_CD":"NIC","OTH_GOVT_ID_TY_TX":"NATIONAL IDENTIFICATION CARD","GVTID":"ID","GVT_ISS_ST_CD":"NY","GVT_ISS_CNTRY_CD":"840","GVTID_ISS_DT":"2010-02-01","GVTID_XPRN_DT":"2019-02-11"}}");

is throwing errors as it is not a correct string